# Can I lock parts of a preformatted HTML code in a document for re-use as form-like template in Notepad++ or other program?

Tags: html, forms, notepad++, editor

Efficiency and time saving question related:

Can I lock parts of a preformatted HTML code in a document for re-use  as form-like template in Notepad++ or other program?

Ideally I would have parts of the document preformated and locked/non editable

and parts Editable/ not locked as follows:

**Bolded** = Locked/non editable

*Italicized* = Editable/ not locked

The purpose is to use the document as a HTML form within the editor (Notepad++ or other one) for easy refill for repetitive work. Without having to paste the same parts again and again.

To use the fillable parts in a form filling way: simply using the tab key to move from filing field to filling field.

The final use would be to copy the HTML code from Notepad++ and paste it on websites comments form.

Example:

**Monday**

*Home*

**9:00**      *Breakfast*

**10:00**     *Workout*

**11:00**     *Reading*

**Tuesday**

*Office*

**9:00**     *Breakfast*

**10:00**    *Work*

**11:00**    *Work*

etc.

Here's the closest answer I could find:
https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/1e72409f/

Comment: So you just want to have a shortcut to paste boilerplate code in your text editor/IDE? If so use https://emmet.io

Comment: Thanks looks great and doing the job. I will give it a try and come back if need be. Thanks again.

Comment: still doing the job? if so would you mind accepting the answer so other users won't feel the need to? if not then feel free to let me know and I'll see if I can help further!

Answer (score 0):

Just converting my comment to an answer for you to accept.

[Emmet.io](https://emmet.io) Is what you need to use for copy and pasting boilerplate code!
Allows you to setup shortcuts across numerous text editors (notepad++ in your case).

Comes with stock shortcuts for Html, css etc. Also allows for customisation of shortcuts easily. Can also change modules in the source code for further customisation.

[Support Docs](https://docs.emmet.io)

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: @Toto You're right. Was early morning and had a long drive to work, no excuse though D: